Is IR Emissivity changed by being submerged in fluids other than air?
I am aware that IR emissivity happens in a vacuum, but treating vacuum as the best case rather than the worst case (where there is nothing adjacent to an emitting atom/surface).
Where should I start to look for an equation or model on IR emission under water or some other arbitrary coating?
Apologies if I have overcomplicated this and a surface under water emits identically and is then simply absorbed as normal by the medium the IR is travelling through (the water in this case).
Example for discussion:
A piece of black high emissivity tape is at 50 degC in air and emits IR at a rate of X
The same piece of tape is then placed in water and will emit IR at rate Y (assume it can ideally be held at 50 degC)
Are X and Y equal?
Thank you for your help.
